# Defining a group morphism using generators

Tags: group-theory

I have just realized something I have taken for granted for a long time might be false, but I can't find a suitable counterexample.

Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups, and suppose $G$ is finitely presented. 
To make things more simple, suppose $G$ has two generators $a$ and $b$ and one relation $\mathcal{R}(a,b) = 1_G  $.

My question is : let $u$ and $v$ be in $H$. Suppose $\mathcal{R}(u,v) = 1_H  $. Does there exist a group morphism $\varphi : G \longrightarrow H$ such that $\varphi (a) = u$ et $\varphi(b) = v$ ?

This result seemed obvious to me until I tried to prove it : first you defined $\varphi$ on the free group, and since  $\mathcal{R}(a,b) = 1_G  $, one might expect that $\varphi$ factorizes. But the trap is that $G$ is the quotient of the normal subgroup generated by $\mathcal{R}$ on which it is not clear $\varphi$ is trivial.

Anyone knows how to prove or unprove that result ?

Comment: Do you mean to assume that $\mathcal{R}(u,v) = 1_H$? Assuming $\mathcal{R}$ is some sort of "polynomial" relation, then $\varphi$ is trivial on $\mathcal{R}$.

Comment: Yes I have edited. Then $\varphi)$ is trivial on $\mathcal{R}$. $\mathcal{R}$ is a word in $a$ and $b$. It is clear $\varphi$ must be trivial on $\mathcal{R}$. But does such a $\varphi$ exist ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, $\phi$ is trivial on the normal subgroup generated by the relations.

The claim is: if $G$ is a group and $S$ is a subset, then any homomorphism $\phi: G \to H$ trivial on $S$ is trivial on the smallest normal subgroup containing $S$. Indeed, $\phi$ is trivial on the kernel of $\phi$, which is a normal subgroup containing $S$.

Comment: (Here my $G$ is the free group, not your $G$.)